# How do I edit a table in order to enable CASCADE DELETE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cascading-deletes

I have a table representing users. When a user is deleted I get:

> DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Apparently, `CASCADE DELETE` is not as easy as I imagined in SQL Server, and the option needs to be added to the table.

The problem is: I cannot figure out how to add the `CASCADE DELETE` option.

I'm using: **SQL Server 2008**. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Read this Microsoft article first. [Read Me](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973.aspx).  I use the GUI during design so here is a picture of how it is selected in SSMS.
[image]
The syntax added to the foreign key is " ON DELETE  CASCADE "

Answer (score 20):

Here's the way I would add the "cascading delete" feature to an **existing** foreign key in *SQL Server Management Studio*.

First, find your foreign key, and open it's "DROP and CREATE To" in a new Query window.

[image: Drop and Create]

Then, just add "`ON DELETE CASCADE`" to the "`ADD CONSTRAINT`" command:

[image: On delete cascade]

Then just hit hit the "Execute" button to run the query.

Job done !

Answer (score 17):

Google `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT`, then `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT`:

[ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275462%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Here's a quick example:

```
CREATE TABLE A 
(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE B 
(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
    CONSTRAINT fk__B__A 
       REFERENCES A (ID)
);

-- Oops! Forgot the CASCADE referential actions.
-- DROP the constraint then recreate it:

ALTER TABLE B DROP
   CONSTRAINT fk__B__A;

ALTER TABLE B ADD
   CONSTRAINT fk__B__A
      FOREIGN KEY (ID)
      REFERENCES A (ID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: I think what the RadiantHex means is RadiantHex wants to delete the rows associated with the constraint using cascading deletes not drop the constraints so the rows may be removed.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss: I think what Mr. TA means is Mr. TA suggests the constraint cannot be altered (i.e. there is no `ALTER TABLE..ALTER CONSTRAINT` syntax), rather the constraint must be dropped then recreated. I've added an example for clarity.