# Can we write a query in SQL Server to cascade delete?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `Employee` and `Address`. I want to delete all employees and their associated addresses in `Address` table. Can we write a single query to do so?

For below query can we use CASCADE keyword?

```
DELETE FROM Employee
```

Comment: Refer this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server

Comment: You need to define the `ON CASCADE DELETE` on the **foreign key** relationship between `Address` and `Employee` - you cannot specify it with when issuing a `DELETE` statement

Answer (score 0):

You can enable set on delete cascade. modify your table sql like this url :

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454861/how-do-i-edit-a-table-in-order-to-enable-cascade-delete)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have foreign keys, easyest way to do this is to use a CTE or a view

```
with MyCTE as ( select T1.ID asT1ID,T2.ID as T2ID from T1 join T2 on T1.id = T2.id) 
Delete MyCTE where T1ID = ???
```

or

```
Create view MyView 
as 
select T1.ID asT1ID,T2.ID as T2ID from T1 join T2 on T1.id = T2.id

delete MyView where T1ID = ??
```