# How to put Cascade on Delete once the Fk constraint has already been defined

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two table and I want to switch on cascade on delete via Query and not via SSMS GUI.

**tblEmployee**

```
Name  GenderId
```

**tblGender**

```
Id    Gender
```

Scenario: Suppose I have already put the foreign key constraint on tblEmployee tblEmployee_GenderId_Fk and now at a later stage I want to add Cascade on Delete, how to achieve it. I looked into the documentation and it tells the *query to add the Cascade on Delete while creating the FK Constraint*. But suppose I forgot to add Cascade that time. Then *how can I add it later*. Something like below

```
Alter table tblgender ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

[Documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php)

Comment: Looks like there is already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454861/how-do-i-edit-a-table-in-order-to-enable-cascade-delete). Please check if it will work for you (people propose to drop and recreate the constraint)

Comment: Turns out, only way out is to drop the constraint and ReAdd it with the cascade on delete.

Comment: Someone please mark this question as Duplicate. I don't think I can with the SO Points I have.